# Uma query por requisição ou uma query só para N requisições?

Tags: terminologia, metodologia

Eu sinceramente não sei se estou perguntando uma coisa bem óbvia, que de cara olhamos e falamos assim: Óbvio que a query dinâmica por requisição é melhor!

Mas vamos lá...

**A aplicação**

Estamos falando de uma aplicação web em ASPNET.MVC 4.0, de indicadores - estilo um dashboard. O tamanho da aplicação eu diria ser pequeno/médio, com banco de dados Oracle.

**Cenário**

Eu preciso fazer N querys para exibir os indicadores. Porém, os filtros podem ser feitos em memória ou direto no banco. A questão é, como estamos falando de indicadores, tenho operações matemáticas envolvidas. Ou seja, eu preciso de um resultado do tipo:

```
ID         Valor         Tipo

1          25560.00      1
2          2330.00       1
3          140.00        2
4          10.00         1
5          50.00         3
6          40.00         3
7          33.00         1
```

No fim das contas....minha requisição seria algo como:

1. Me mostre uma porcentagem de todos os IDs que possuam Tipo = 1
2. Me mostre uma porcentagem de todos os IDs que possuam Tipo = 2
3. Me mostre uma porcentagem de todos os IDs que possuam Tipo = 3

**Pergunta**

O que é melhor?

1. Fazer uma requisição só trazendo todos os IDS com todos os Tipos, colocando todos os dados dentro da ViewBag, fazer as operações matemáticas via JS e também filtrar o Tipo via JS?
2. Fazer todas as operações no banco, exibir a informação consolidada na aplicação e ir no banco quantas vezes for requisitado?

Comment: Eu acho que com as informações que você está dando não dá pra responder. Não está claro quais seriam as operações matemáticas nem por que você precisaria de múltiplas queries. Olhando o exemplo, uma única query com agregação (`GROUP BY...`) parece que resolveria, no banco, facilmente.

Comment: Eu tenho uma fórmula para exibir o que eu quero.... O ponto é: fazer toda a operação no banco para cada requisição ou simplesmente trazer tudo na viewbag e tratar tudo via JS?

Comment: Não existe resposta precisa pra isso, depende do caso! Em geral é preferível fazer no banco, mas também não é desejável fazer muitas requisições.

Comment: O problema é que é um assunto meio que old-school, sabe? Na epoca que o processamento de dados e uso de memória era bem caro... não existe um pensamento ou teoria para os "dias atuais"?

Comment: Eu também acho que não existe resposta correta. Cada caso é um caso. Qual é o objetivo a ser alcançado? Maior velocidade, maior legibilidade, maior facilidade de desenvolvimento, maior facilidade de escalabilidade, maior interatividade, menor trafego, menor stress do servidor, menor tempo de desenvolvimento,etc.

Comment: O objetivo é: maior rapidez na hora de filtrar e menor custo para o banco.